# How to pull custom field data into Wordpress shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, shortcode

I am creating a series of shortcodes that link to pages on a custom post type called `heroes`. I was wondering how I can link the info in my shortcode to that custom post type's post so I can pull in custom field data into the shortcode to use.

Here is the shortcode I am using

```
add_shortcode('illidan', 'illidan');

function illidan($args) {
    $default = array('icon' => 'true');
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $default);

    $herotip = '';
    if ($args['icon']) {
        $herotip.= '<img src="http://stormable.com/img/heroes/illidan/illidan-ab1.png">';
    }

    $herotip.= '<a href="http://stormable.com/heroes/illidan/">Illidan</a>
    This is where I would like to pull in custom field data from the post illidan
    For example <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "health-lvl1", true); ?>
    ';

    return $herotip;
}
```

So under the link I would like to be able to pull in data that I have in custom fields from the post `Illidan` under the custom post type `heroes` although I'm not sure how to link it to that page.

Comment: `global $post` is all you need to access the current post.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is that this won't be on the current post it will be other other posts through out the site.

Comment: Then you'll need to create a new query based on your requirements, then perform the normal loop iteration. `if($posts->have_posts(); while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post(); // endwhile; endif;`

Comment: How do I add that in my into my shortcode? just put the php right into it?

Comment: So, the `Illidan` post has the following URL: `http://stormable.com/heroes/illidan/`? Will the URL ever change? Or the post ID?

Comment: @brasofilo Yes that is the url and the post id is 11 and neither will ever change.

Comment: @Greenhoe do you want this shortcode for only `illidan` post?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I will only want to pull the custom field data from the illidan post but the actual short code will be placed all over the site in different posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This return the custom field value from the post meta

```
 // returns the value of health-gain
 $health_gain = get_post_meta( 11, 'health-gain', true); 


 $herotip.= '<a href="http://stormable.com/heroes/illidan/">Illidan</a>
This is where I would like to pull in custom field data from the post illidan
For example '. $health_gain;
```

take a look on this link [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), Implement it into your shortcode function where ever you want.

I Suggest you to take a look on this article http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/, tells you the more robust and right way to create a shortcode.

Comment: Thank you, and I've been using that article as a guide, although I'm not the greatest with PHP yet. How do I echo get_post_meta( 11, 'health-gain'); inside the '' that I have along with the link since it seems like anything I put in there just shows up as HTML

Comment: Thank you that works great, one last question. Under the get_post_meta instead of the using the post id number is there a way to use the posts slug instead?

Comment: @Greenhoe for this you have to use the WP_Query, and have to make a query that find the specific post name(illidan) under specific post_type(heroes) that will return you the post id of that specific post.

Comment: @Greenhoe but if you have same custom field in every post then you have to use `$post->ID` instead of WP_Query with global $post;